# passwords database - access control and/or synchronization

Tags: password-management, access-control

so, we've got a ton of passwords that several different administrators need to have access to, each with their unique password/key/user/whatever...
it needs to be either centralized, or the passwords database need be synchronized between all admins.
any simple suggestions for a solution here?
most machines operate on either RH/CentOS or OpenBSD...

Comment: Which kind of access? Un*x passwd database, Samba or more confined solution? Did you use nis, radius or other such a centralized solution?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your threat / work model, [LastPass Enterprise](https://lastpass.com/enterprise_overview.php) might be exactly what you're looking for. It's a web-based password management service, allowing access from pretty much anywhere that has an internet connection. As long as you've got a browser, you should be able to get at the site. It might even work with ncurses-based browsers if you're lucky!

Features:

- Shared password management.
- Random password generation.
- Passwords encrypted on the server, unlocked by user passwords.
- Detailed access reports.
- Easy revocation of access.
- Various export formats, including CSV, in case you ever want to import the passwords into a local repository like [KeePass](http://keepass.info/help/base/importexport.html).

At time of writing, prices are 24 USD per year for an enterprise account that gives you up to 100 users, and they offer a free trial.

Comment: Oh, and in case you're wondering, I've got no affiliation with them whatsoever - the above is simply based on what's on their site and what I've heard other say! :)

Comment: for additional choice, could also try CyberArk  (again, no affiliation)

Comment: oh, god no, lol.

Comment: looking for a solution that keeps the passwords within the company network..

Comment: @episteme Any particular reason? A breach of the site shouldn't result in any passwords being stolen, since they're encrypted with the master passwords of the users.

Comment: @Polynomial derived from a sub-standard 500 iterations of PBKDF2 with SHA-1